# TWRS Flashing Error: E2001: Failed to update vendor image

Tags: android, operating-system, lineageos

i tried to flash Lineage OS on my Galaxy A3 (2017).

Unfortunaly im getting the following Error:

"E2001: Failed to update vendor image."

PS: This also happen with other Operation Systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To everyone who is getting this Problem in the Future:

Just flash the following File:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-a320fl-f-y-repartition-script-for-vendor-support.3951105/